# Regex for word exclusion in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular expression `'[\w_-]+'` which allows alphanumberic character or underscore.

I have a set of words in a python list which I don't want to allow

```
listIgnore = ['summary', 'config']
```

What changes need to be made in the regex?

P.S: I am new to regex

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Comment: Agree that it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question intrigued me, so I set about for an answer:

```
'^(?!summary)(?!config)[\w_-]+$'
```

Now this only works if you want to match the regex against a complete string:

```
>>> re.match('^(?!summary)(?!config)[\w_-]+$','config_test')
>>> (None)
>>> re.match('^(?!summary)(?!config)[\w_-]+$','confi_test')
>>> <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x21d34a8>
```

So to use your list, just add in more `(?!<word here>)` for each word after `^` in your regex. These are called lookaheads. [Here's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html) some good info.

If you're trying to match within a string (i.e. without the `^` and `$`) then I'm not sure it's possible. For instance the regex will just pick a subset of the string that doesn't match. Example: `ummary` for `summary`.

Obviously the more exclusions you pick the more inefficient it will get. There's probably better ways to do it.

Comment: Probably, filtering all found values - like in thefourtheye's answer - will be more effective (re may be a memory-crunching bitch)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> line="This is a line containing a summary of config changes"
>>> listIgnore = ['summary', 'config']
>>> patterns = "|".join(listIgnore)
>>> print re.findall(r'\b(?!(?:' + patterns + r'))[\w_-]+', line)
['This', 'is', 'a', 'line', 'containing', 'a', 'of', 'changes']
```